# how to import an existing IAM role for access the S3 bucket

Tags: aws-lambda, notifications, amazon-iam, roles, amazon-ecr

I want to create a trigger on an Amazon S3 bucket, so that if any json files are uploaded, the existing Lambda function will pull the object and convert into a .csv file, then save that file into another S3 bucket. Please let me know if any changes in my code.

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_ecr as _ecr,
    aws_s3_deployment as s3deploy,
    aws_s3_notifications as s3_notify,
    core as cdk
)
from aws_cdk import core

class MyClass(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # creating buckets
        bucket_source = s3.Bucket(self, "bucket_source")
        bucket_dest = s3.Bucket(self, "bucket_dest")

        s3deploy.BucketDeployment(self, "CreatingDir",
            sources=[s3deploy.Source.asset("./lambdatestout2")],
            destination_bucket=bucket_dest,
            destination_key_prefix="output"
)
        repo = _ecr.Repository.from_repository_name(self, "Repository", repository_name="myrepo")
        lambdaFn = _lambda.DockerImageFunction(
            self, "My Function",
             code=_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr(
             repository=repo,
             tag="convert"),
            timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(600),
            memory_size=1024,
            environment={
                    "dest_file_format":"csv",
                    "output_bucket":"bucket_source1",
                    "prefix":"output"
               }
)
        # Create trigger for Lambda function using suffix
        notification = s3_notify.LambdaDestination(lambdaFn)
        notification.bind(self, bucket_source)
        # Add Create Event only for .csv files
        bucket_source.add_object_created_notification(
        notification, s3.NotificationKeyFilter(suffix='.json')
#    role = role
)
```

Comment: Does it work? Are you experiencing any particular problems?

Comment: Done! imported the IAM Role in the code

Comment: What is your question? If it is working, then there's nothing to suggest.